# QSqlRelationalTableModel insertRecord doesn't work if call setRelation

Tags: sqlite, qt

editlistofcustomers.h

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel *RelationalModel;
TreeModel *CategoriesModel;
QSqlRecord Record;
```

editlistofcustomers.cpp
EditListOfCustomers::EditListOfCustomers // constructor

```
RelationalModel = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, *SupportObj->GetDataBase());
RelationalModel->setTable(SupportObj->GetCustomersTableName());
RelationalModel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
RelationalModel->select();
RelationalModel->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Название/имя покупателя"));
Record = RelationalModel->record();
RelationalModel->setRelation(2, QSqlRelation(SupportObj->GetCategoriesOfCustomersTableName(),
                         SupportObj->GetCategoriesOfCustomersPattern()[0].GetName(), // ID.
                         SupportObj->GetCategoriesOfCustomersPattern()[2].GetName())); // Name.
CategoriesModel = new TreeModel(QObject::tr("Категории"),
                SupportObj->GetCategoriesOfCustomersTableName(),
                SupportObj, this);


//Setup model view delegate.
ui->TV_ListOfCustomers->setModel(RelationalModel);
ui->TV_ListOfCustomers->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui->TV_ListOfCustomers));
ui->TV_ListOfCustomers->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->TV_ListOfCustomers->setSortingEnabled(true);

ui->TV_CategoryOfCustomer->setModel(CategoriesModel);
SupportObj->GetDataBase()->transaction()
```

EditListOfCustomers::AddCustomer

```
QString customerName = ui->LE_CustomerName->text();
if(!customerName.isEmpty())
{
    Record.setValue(SupportObj->GetCustomersPattern()[1].GetName(), QVariant(customerName)); // Name.
    int categoryID = CategoriesModel->GetItemID(ui->TV_CategoryOfCustomer->currentIndex());
    Record.setValue(SupportObj->GetCustomersPattern()[2].GetName(), QVariant(categoryID)); // Category ID.
    Record.setValue(SupportObj->GetCustomersPattern()[3].GetName(), QVariant(ui->LE_CustomerTelephoneNumbers->text())); // Telephone numbers.
    Record.setValue(SupportObj->GetCustomersPattern()[4].GetName(), QVariant(ui->LE_CustomerAddress->text())); // Address.
    Record.setValue(SupportObj->GetCustomersPattern()[5].GetName(), QVariant(ui->TE_CustomerComment->toPlainText())); // Comment.
    RelationalModel->insertRecord(-1, Record);
    if(!RelationalModel->submitAll())
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "CategoriesEditor::CategoriesEditor", SupportObj->GetDataBase()->lastError().text());
    }

    // Clear fields
    ui->LE_CustomerName->clear();
    ui->TV_CategoryOfCustomer->setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex());
    ui->LE_CustomerTelephoneNumbers->clear();
    ui->LE_CustomerAddress->clear();
    ui->TE_CustomerComment->clear();

    ui->LE_CustomerName->setFocus();
    ui->TV_ListOfCustomers->sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
}
```

If comment "RelationalModel->setRelation( ... )" everything work fine: transaction, adding, deleting, commit or rollback. If uncomment nothing work, but show everything right(ID replaced by category name), but I can't insert new row using "insertRecord". I try [this](http://blog.oh-mypixel.com/qt-qsqlrelationaltablemodel-and-insertrecord-foreign-key-cannot-be-null/)
suggestion, but unsuccessfully.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in the column name. `setRelation` changes column name `category_of_customer_id` to `category_of_customers_name_2`.

The solution use [`void setValue(int index, const QVariant &val)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsqlrecord.html#setValue) instead of [`void setValue(const QString & name, const QVariant &val)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsqlrecord.html#setValue-2).

```
QSqlRecord record = RelationalModel->record();
record.setValue(1, QVariant(customerName)); // Name.
int categoryID = CategoriesModel->GetItemID(ui->TV_CategoryOfCustomer->currentIndex());
record.setValue(2, QVariant(categoryID)); // Category ID.
record.setValue(3, QVariant(ui->LE_CustomerTelephoneNumbers->text())); // Telephone numbers.
record.setValue(4, QVariant(ui->LE_CustomerAddress->text())); // Address.
record.setValue(5, QVariant(ui->TE_CustomerComment->toPlainText())); // Comment.
RelationalModel->insertRecord(-1, record);
if(!RelationalModel->submitAll())
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "CategoriesEditor::CategoriesEditor", SupportObj->GetDataBase()->lastError().text());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue.  This only needs to happen for the field that has a setRelation.  Here's the solution for PyQt:

```
def insertRow(self):      
    rec = self.record()
    rec.setValue("id", "new id")
    rec.setValue("type", 1)
    rec.setValue("title", "new title")
    return self.insertRecord(-1, rec)
    self.submit()
```

Apologies.  Wanted to comment, but don't yet have a reputation of 50+.